# Letters with dot below can not be found by sqlite query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to build a mobile dictionary application which contains some words that composed by the letters like 'ḳ' or 'ạ'.

I preferred sqlite db for this application. When I query the words that contain these letters by not dotted versions, It can not find the word.

For example, the word 'abacırıḳ' can not be found by the query below.

```
select * from Kelime where KaracaycaAnlam like '%ık%';
```

*Sqlite Result*

[image]

When I export the same table to mysql db and run the same query, I can get the result as shown below.

[image]

I searched on the internet about changing character coding of sqlite database. I could not find anything useful. How can I get the same result by using sqlite database?

Comment: Please, read this: [SQLite LIKE operator](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/)

Comment: ["SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default."](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), in other words, you'll need to add the ICU extension to SQLite if you want the LIKE operator to support casefolding.

Comment: @AnonCoward [linking with anchor](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators)

Comment: Thanks @Maciej. I read it but I can not find what I am looing for. When I type '%k%'(without dot), I want to list all words that contains 'ḳ' (dotted).

Comment: @AnonCoward I did some research on ICU extension. I could not figure out how to add it to SQLite. Can you explain it as detailed please ?